# how to write java code inside scala template in java play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

is it possible to write java code inside the scala template. if yes any sample code please

```
  @while(@resultSet.next()) {
                   println("Mani");
                 String name=@resultSet.getString("name");
                Int  in=@resultSet.getInt("id");
                 println("Name:"+name)
                 print( name + ", " + in);

                  }
```

Comment: This can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368995/mixing-scala-and-java-in-play-framework

Comment: Ouch, for real, a resultset in PlayFramework **view**? Transform that to some other object before giving it to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jesper says here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357926/2935464 you will be able to access your regular Java classes and objects in Scala as long as you use the Scala syntax.